# Communication between Intranet Applications

Tags: ipc, communication

I have two separate web applications, both in the same intranet.

One of the two is a legacy application, strictly a static site, being served via Apache.

The other application is new, one that I am currently building, and will be a dynamic site, with a database.

In the first application I want to have a few form pages, that collect information, and have the information processed (posted to) and saved in the second applications database.

I have never had an application accept a post from a different application, so I do not know the best way to proceed. If there is a better idea than doing a post, please say so.
Also, do I need to do anything in particular, like a particular configuration, to have the second application accept information from the first application.

In case it matters, I have full control of the second application, and thus far I am using Glassfish as the application server, java as the language, and I am using Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're describing a situation where your new site is basically a [RESTful web service](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/restful/) providing functionality to your old, legacy site.  There is nothing wrong with this architecture ... in fact, it's quite common. :)

Comment: i'm assuming you are saying the second application will have a RESTful web service that the first application will call? If so, can the first application call the RESTful service from an html page that has a form on it (sort of like a post to the second application)?